# Magento Backend Session Timeout Issue

Tags: magento-1.8, backend

I was working in my backend saving new custom block while my session expires out very much earlier than expected.
I checked my session timeout limit. And Tried once more to work on custom block, and same issue happening each time.
Question is, Why session is expiring sooner than session timeout limit ???

Answer (score 2):

Try this process,
1. Login to Magento
2. System > Configuraiton > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (seconds)
3. Input the number of seconds that you want to set as the timeout
4. Save

Comment: Its not working. Thanks for Help. But I think, Admin Session expires before completing Session Lifetime while working on WYSIWYG Editor. I tried on Catalog too. Same issue while adding image in WYSIWYG Editor and Clicking on Save  Button.